# TOAST UI Image Editor for Angular 11

Tags: angular, toast-ui-image-editor

Have anyone gotten the Toast Image Editor to work for Angular 2+ (I have Angular 11)? I am currently trying to make this work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tui-image-editor-angular

I want it to work with the 'loadImageFromURL', but when I use this all the edit buttons are disabled. If I load an image from the 'Load file' button, it works. Then the edit buttons is not disabled. So it seems like something is not initialized when using the 'loadImageFromURL'.

One issue with using this package is that the 'options' does not contain the 'includeUI -> loadImage -> path' which probably needs to be added for the editor to enable the buttons.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did this work for you? Or did you get any good alternative?

Comment: @Swamy No it didn't work so I used this one instead and customized it. It's pretty good: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-photo-editor

Comment: Thank you @TommyF 
npmjs.com/package/ngx-photo-editor - Looked at this and it has cropping and other capabilities. 
We are looking for both cropping and drawing on image capabilities, like pencil and eraser etc.